# Bokeh Gives me an Empty Plot with ColumnDataSource

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I'm a newbie on Bokeh. Been playing around with it successfully and have managed to plot beautiful charts.. But I think some of my basics are still flawed.

I tried the following simple example, and I end up with an empty plot. 
I believe this is due to the x axis data being strings? But I'm unable to figure out why, and how to fix it.

Below is the code I tried:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
import pandas as pd

scores = [['Tom', 85], ['Dick', 30], ['Harry', 60], ['Sally', 80], ['Jimmy', 70], ['Raj', 50]]
scores_df = pd.DataFrame(scores, columns=['Name', 'Score'])

source = ColumnDataSource(scores_df)

fig = figure(title='my chart', plot_width=300, plot_height=300, y_range=(0,100), x_axis_label='Name', y_axis_label='Score')
fig.vbar(x='Name', top='Score', bottom=0, source=source, width=1, color='black')

output_notebook()
show(fig)
```

And this is the output I get:

[image: Empty Plot]

Please help me understand what i'm missing here?

Comment: Based on further reading, I've come to understand that I might have to pass the x_range explicitly as the x_axis consists of of nominal values.

However, since the source is a ColumnDataSource, I'm not sure how to explicitly refer to the 'Name' field as the x_range when initialising the figure. Wonder if I'm on the right path there..

Answer (score 1):

I believe Bokeh needs an x-range defined in some cases with vBar (especially when categoricals are strings), correct me if I'm wrong!

By adding x_range=scores_df['Name'] to the figure;

```
fig = figure(title='my chart', plot_width=300, plot_height=300, y_range=(0,100), x_axis_label='Name', y_axis_label='Score', x_range=scores_df['Name'])
```

The bar chart is plotted
[my chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAM7G.png)

Comment: In fact, you might be correct. In my previous comment, I shared this same observation. The doc talks along the same lines too: 

[Handling Categorical Data](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html)

However, I was wondering if there is a way to refer to the range using the ColumnDataSource directly, and not having to reference the higher level source (dataframe in this case), but looks like not.